# Почему не работает Grid в Ant-Design

Tags: reactjs, ant-design

Установил, отображает названия классов antd в Elements в Chrome
[image: Elements в Chrome]

Импотрирую так:

`import {Row, Col} from 'antd';`

В коде все написал так, как на сайте Ant Design представлено
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но почему-то отображается некорректно
Должно быть по сути 2 колонки, но они отображаются как 2 строки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста как решить данную проблему.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена! Не подключил в App.css antd.css

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).